# How to register a CAB file

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, activex, cab

I'm using an `ActiveX` packed in a `CAB` file within a solution in Visual Studio, this `CAB` file contains 2 files a `abc.inf` and a `abcInstaller.msi`.

I'v adjusted the settings in `IE` so the `ActiveX` gets installed.
By running the application in `IE` it asks to allow installing this `ActiveX` as expected, the `ActiveX` installs correctly but gets not registered so I'm trying to do it manually 
by running a `regMyActiveX.reg` file containing the following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Salihane.Group]
@="SLGP.SalihaneGroup"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Salihane.Group\CLSID]
@="{121C3E0E-DC6E-45DC-952B-A6617F0FAA32}"
```

As far as I know, if the ActiveX is installed and registered then it should do its job but it does not work. I think I'm registering it on the wrong place or way. Is my reg file wrong or could it be something else?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell us more about "it does not work".

Comment: I'm using a method in the ActiveX to read XML files from C:\temp, the ActiveX should read those files en get me list of data back. now I get an empty list, this means the ActiveX does not work properly. It worked fine on another pc but this pc is now formatted and the problem is in the registration I believe, where and how was the ActiveX registered on the other pc so it worked fine,but on my machine it works not because its not properly registered. I'm 95% sure that it has to do with registration.